# Read config(Having nested configuration)file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, configuration

I have a `.conf` file, which has data like:

```
category1 {
  Key1="value1"
  Key2="value2"
}
```

How do I read these values in bash?

Answer (score 1):

An HCL parser could read the data that you have posted.  HCL is HashiCorp's structured document format that they use for configuration files (see e.g. [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/syntax/configuration)).

There are tools available for converting HCL into more common structured formats such as JSON.  One such tool is `yj` (from https://github.com/sclevine/yj).

```bash
$ cat file
category1 {
  Key1="value1"
  Key2="value2"
}
```

```bash
$ yj -cj <file
{"category1":[{"Key1":"value1","Key2":"value2"}]}
```

The `-cj` option makes `yj` convert from HCL to JSON (see `yj -h` for the complete list of available options).

Note that `yj` turns the `category1` section into an array. If the input HCL file had an additional `category1` section, the additional section would be another element in the array.

Once in JSON form, we may use the commonly available JSON processor `jq` to extract the data that we need:

```bash
$ yj -cj <file | jq -r '.category1[0].Key1'
value1
```

The `jq` expression picks out the value corresponding to the `Key1` key in the first element of the `category1` array.  The `sr` option ensures we get "raw-data" back from `jq` and not a JSON-encoded quoted string.

Extracting into a variable could be done with a command substitution:

```bash
$ val1=$(yj -cj <file | jq -r '.category1[0].Key1')
$ printf '1st value = %s\n' "$val1"
1st value = value1
```